# Java libraries for animation (for sorting algorithms)

Tags: library, java, animation

I am new to Java and I am trying to figure out if there is a relatively quick way of animating sorting algorithms in Java.

I have already coded up my algorithms (quick sort, bubble, and shell) and want to animate them using an applet but am having difficulty in thinking of a way to visually demonstrate what's going on.

**Are there any libraries or classes I can use to do this?**

Comment: You can get some ideas on how to visualize the algorithms in the answers provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809288/different-sort-algorithms-visually-performed

Answer (score 1):

Consider Trident animation library.

Here is the link: https://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home